# WEKA pattern investigation with Apriori , I don't get results

Tags: weka, apriori

I want to extract knowledge from the competition data
KDD Cup 1999. This dataset includes records about connections to the
Internet, where each connection refers to an attack or a normal usage. The
dataset contains 41 attributes and 4.898.431 records . I want to  perform data correlation using the
Apriori algorithm , investigate the patterns extracted and
evaluate the results . All that using WEKA .

A sample of the arff file before any preprocessing looks like this :
[image]

So I understand that in order to run Apriori in WEKA  all attributes must be nominal so I use the "NumericToNominal" filter in WEKA to convert some numeric fields to nominal  . The new file looks like this :
[image]

So I take my new file and run Apriori . but I get no results .
First I tried running the whole file but it kept loading untill it crashes , out of memory .I increased the memory but it keeps crashing so I took my original file and left only 20 records out of all just to test . Even then the programm just keeps loading without giving me any results .After  a lot of searching I am assuming it has something to do with the data format . I thought that after using the built in filter my data would be in correct form ,but it seems there is  more preprocessing that must be done . So how am I supposed to restructure my data and in what format excactly ?
It is a really complex file for me so I am a bit lost, any help is really appreciated .

Thanks a lot for your time in advance !

Comment: Can you run Apriori successfully using default options on the [supermarket.arff](https://git.cms.waikato.ac.nz/weka/weka/-/blob/main/trunk/wekadocs/data/supermarket.arff) dataset that comes with Weka?

Comment: @fracpete  Yes I tried it , it works just fine for the supermarket.arff .

Comment: On the dataset that I generated, I tried running Apriori on the first 20 rows as well and it wouldn't stop. After applying the [RemoveUseless](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RemoveUseless.html) filter, it completed within seconds (only 7 attributes left). It's possible that the single-valued attributes are causing problems with the algorithm. The full dataset, however, will take a very long time, since Apriori in general is not a very fast or efficient algorithm.

Comment: I made it run at last, I played with the option  treat 0 as missing values etc . To be honest  I don't really know what fixed it but it works , thanks a lot for your time !